# windows recover file after point restauration

Tags: windows-server-2003

I had a problem with a Windows Server 2003

A previous version (restore point) was restored on the server

Could I recover a file created after this restore point?

And, if this is possible, how to recover such files?

Comment: There's no such thing as a Restore Point for Windows Server 2003. What exactly did you restore and from where?

Comment: Please keep noted that Windows 2003 is EOL since July 14, 2015 and you are REALLY running into security issues when you still us that. You should start using the solution to a newer OS. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003

Comment: @joeqwerty Well... I dont know and I post a question to figure out what happened http://serverfault.com/questions/815213/windows-server-2003-restore-a-previous-version-for-unknown-reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a backup or copy of the file that was made *after* the file was modified, then no.

If you are feeling really, really lucky, you *might* have a shadow copy, but that depends on exactly how the restore was done. Right-click the file, go to properties, and click "Previous Version". But if there is anything in there, go out and buy a lottery ticket because you are clearly on a roll.

Comment: No shadow copy :'(